# How to start reading shapefile in QGIS using python console?

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, qgis-python-console, pyshp

How do I start reading shapefile using Python console in QGIS?

I am sharing the script that I am trying to follow, however, it gives me an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Using Vector Layers](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html).

For example:

```
shapefile_path = r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/buildings.shp'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(shapefile_path, 'templayer') #Create a layer object
all_features = [f for f in layer.getFeatures()] #List all features
first_feature = all_features[0]

#Read one attribute
#first_feature['ogc_fid']
#244689

#All attributes
#first_feature.attributes()
#[244689, 331, 'Hus, storlek 1', 0.0, NULL, NULL, '1912-12-12 12:00', 'house', NULL]

#Geometry
#first_feature.geometry()
#<QgsGeometry: Point (653047.7118750000372529 6539581.28149999957531691)>
```

[image]